# UIButton press and hold Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift4.2

I'm attempting to use a UIButton to increment an integer in an iPhone app. I want the user to be able to press and hold as opposed to just repeatedly tapping. I can create an `IBAction` for the `UIButton` using Touch Drag Inside, but it repeats too quickly.

I've thought of using a `for` loop that only increments the integer every 100 cycles or so, but that seems like a hack and an inefficient use of resources.

I've also thought of using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter()`, but it will have the same end result, only it takes longer for you to see it.

Any ideas?